# How to set the orientation to portrait in firebase UI in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using firebase UI for authentication, In case of ioS the orientation is not an issue, 
In case of android if the screen orientation of phone is auto rotated, the firebase UI will also get rotated.

- I have set the application orientation to portrait in manifest
- I have also added code to make my activity portrait in my class.

Setting a custom UI to the Firebase UI with style

```
    <style name="FirebaseLoginTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

does not worked. Is their any way to restrict it to portrait.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by it "does not work"?  Forcing to portrait isn't really a solution, especially for Android TV users.

Comment: My app is in potrait mode, but if auto rotation is enabled firbase ui gets rotated @ Doug Stevenson

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem with Firebase UI in this situation?

Comment: `android:screenOrientation="portrait" ` set this to inside application tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FirebaseUI login orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607336/firebaseui-login-orientation)

Answer (score 1):

add your a orientation in manifest file like this :

```
<activity
       android:name=".YourActivity"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       android:theme="@style/FirebaseLoginTheme" />
```

Your Style

```
  <style name="FirebaseLoginTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
   <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: @Milan Pansuriya , no it does not work still the app can be rotated

Answer (score 1):

Just call `setLockOrientation(true)` on `AuthUI.SignInIntentBuilder` object

For example:

```
startActivityForResult(auth.createSignInIntentBuilder().setAvailableProviders(idProviders).setLockOrientation(true).build(), RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by setting the portrait mode programmatically in every activity.
If you target Android 8+ you may get an error  'Only fullscreen activities can request orientation' from some com.firebase.ui.auth.ui activities and that's why I've used a try catch but your login activity will be still locked to the portrait mode.

Add this in your application class and remember to include it in your manifest's application tag (`android:name=".MyApplication"`)

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{


public MyApplication() {

}


    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

            try {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }catch (Exception e){
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**add this to your manifest :**

```
 <activity
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:name="com.firebase.ui.auth.KickoffActivity"
            tools:replace="android:theme"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

And FYI this is my AppTheme (this exists in style.xml)

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```