# FirebaseUI forced landscape mode

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I use FirebaseUI for register user. My application always use landscape mode. When on device disabled auto landscape mode, that at opened `AuthUI` window device set portrait mode. How make `AuthUI` opened on landscape mode?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="...">
    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Theme for `AuthUI`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AuthUI_theme" parent="@style/FirebaseUI">
        <item name="android:screenOrientation">landscape</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Code:

```
val at = AuthUI.getInstance(...).setTheme(R.style.AuthUI_theme).build()
```

Comment: Try adding this line in your manifest inside <activity></activity> tags: 
tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"

Comment: @SlothCoding sorry, this no worked

Comment: I found this, so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41979482/14759470

Comment: @SlothCoding hmm...sorry:c